# how to get value from json via variable in typescript?

Tags: json, typescript

supposing I have to read some data from some json files(i18n), every json file may look like:

```json
{
  "foo": "1",
  "bar": "2",
  ...
}
```

I don't know how many fields this json have(it can be expanded), but it's fields look like

```json
{
 [prop: string]: string
}
```

besides, all the json files share the same fields.
when I try to read a value from this json via:

```
//a can be expanded, I'm not sure how many fileds does it have
let a = {
    name: "dd",
    addr: "ee",
}

//I'm confident a has a field "name"
let b = "name";

console.log(a[b]);
```

the error message is:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type
```

how could I fix it?

Comment: I just tested. No any error message. Everything is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering is because the keys in `a` is not just *any* string (in fact, it can only be "name" or "add"), but `b` can be a string of *any* arbitrary value. If you are very sure that `b` represents a key found in the object `a`, you can hint TypeScript as such:

```
let b: keyof typeof a = "name";
```

Attempting to assign any arbitrary string value to `b` will lead to an error:

```
// This will cause an error
let b: key typeof a = "foobar";
```

See proof-of-concept on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTCGAIGNQO3AjApuRAPADrAJorAacASQHIBbcGAewBdwBnAVwCdkALSgd3FNgE9wAZgEsANrjrgslRBKG1WoAG6IAUGNoQAvOADeK8AYqhSiAFzgARFiwW8%20w6GtNzFxIlsqAvipUgS5SEoYYRwYDXAFCQhhRBEsSxhjdzVEWnhzAGtEXkoBcGpedERc8C0EpIsAbh9AmDpKMQA6EUoAcwAKUABteABdAEpKoA).